# Batching in LWE based Crypto-System

Tags: lwe

Is batching possible for a LWE based crypto-system like we do for a RLWE based one?

Comment: Try this paper by Brakerski, Gentry and Halevi: http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/565

Comment: Yes.  This was first done in Peikert-Waters STOC'08, and in a simpler fashion in Peikert-Vaikuntanathan-Waters CRYPTO'08.